# emencia.django.newsletter datetime problems with django 1.4

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am using `emencia.django.newsletter`. When I run `python manage.py send_newsletter' I get this error

`if self.newsletter.sending_date <= datetime.now() and \
TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

This is where the error comes from:

```
def can_send(self):

    """Check if the newsletter can be sent"""
if self.test:
    return True

if self.newsletter.sending_date <= datetime.now() and\
   (self.newsletter.status == Newsletter.WAITING or\
    self.newsletter.status == Newsletter.SENDING):
    return True

return False
```

I use Django 1.4

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sending_date` value is *timezone aware*, but `datetime.now()` is *timezone naive*. As the error message says, you cannot compare them.

The answer is to convert `now` into a timezone aware datetime before doing the comparison.

```
import datetime
from django.utils.timezone import utc

now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
if self.newsletter.sending_date <= now and \
    ...
```

For more information see the Django docs on [naive and aware datetime objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects).